# construct an orthogonal family of support projections by Zorn's lemma

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra and $NS(M)$ be its normal state space.

Set $P_0(M):=\{s_{\phi}: \phi \in NS(M)\}$. There is a conclusion: For any projection $p\in M$, it follows from Zorn's lemma that there is an orthogonal family $(P_i)_{i\in I}$ in $P_0(M)$ satisfying $p=\sum_{i\in I} P_i$. Where $s_{\phi}$ is the support projection of the normal state $\phi$.

I tried to construct a partial orederd set as following :

Set $S_p=\{J：p=\sum_{j\in J}P_j, P_j\in P_0(M), P_iP_j=0 \quad \text{for any }i\neq j\}$, $S_p$ is ordered by inclusion.  But I cannot check every chain in $S_p$ has a upper bound in $S_p$.

Comment: What is $P_0(M)$? Are these the support projections? (What is a support projection?) Also I thnk you have not written $S_p$ correctly. With your $S_p$ what you want to check is: "$S_p$ is non-empty" rather than "there is a maximal element of $S_p$".

Comment: Yes, I reedited the question. $P_0(M)$ is the set of all support projections in $M$.

Comment: How to construct the partial order set?

Comment: Let $\phi$ be a normal state. Is the following the correct definition of a support projection?  $$P_\phi := \inf (\{ P \text{ projection }\mid \phi(PA)=\phi(A) \text{ for all }A\in M \text{ and }P\text{ is central in } M\})$$

Comment: I guess "central" should be removed, the condition should rather be $\phi(PA)=\phi(A)=\phi(AP)$, right?

Comment: Yes, in Takesaki's book , the support projection is defined as following : if $\omega$ is a nonzero normal positube linear functional, then there exists a unique nonzeo projection $s(\omega)\in M$ such that $\omega$ is faithful on $s(\omega)Ms(\omega)$ and $\omega=s(\omega)\omega=s(\omega)\omega s(\omega)$. We call $s(\omega)$ the support projction of $\omega$.

Comment: Ok, I think its elementary that your definition implies my definition (without the central), but the other implication might be non-elementary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following set:
$$S_p:=\left\{ J \subseteq P_0(M)\ \middle|\ \sum_{P\in J}P \le p,\quad P\cdot Q = 0 \text{ for all $P,Q$ in $J$} \right\}$$
ie $S_p$ consists of all sets of mutually orthogonal support projections that sum up to something less than $p$ (this sum is to be understood to converge in the ultra-weak topology or in SOT or in whatever von Neumann topology you like to look at). Give this an order relation
$$J\leq I :\iff \sum_{P\in J} P \leq \sum_{P\in I} P,$$
ie $J$ is less than $I$ if the sum over $I$ is closer to the upper bound $p$.

Now for any chain $J_i$ in $S_p$ define $J:=\bigcup_i J_i$.All projections in $J$ will remain mutually orthogonal and their sum will remain less than the upper bound $p$. Hence $J\in S_p$ and obviously $J\ge J_i$ for all $i$. By Zorn's Lemma there are maximal elements of $S_p$.

Whats left is to check that any maximal element of $S_p$ must necessarily sum up to $p$. Suppose that $J$ is a maximal element and denote with $P_J=\sum_{P\in J}P$. Then $p-P_J$ is an orthogonal projection, if it isn't $=0$ then there must be some support projection $P'\leq p-P_J$, you can then check that $J\cup\{P'\}\geq J$, contradicting maximality.

Comment: Why $S_p$ is not empty?

Comment: Indeed, the argument for $S_p$ being non-empty is the same as the one implying the existence of a $P'\leq p-P_J$, I didn't carry it out because I was not sure about the correct definition of a support projection. Let $p$ be a projection and let $x$ be an element of the underlying Hilbertspace that lies in the image of $p$, denote the projection onto $x$ by $P_x$ (this need not be in $M$). The map $\phi_x:A\mapsto Tr(P_xA)$ is clearly a normal state. You have that $\phi_x(pA)=\phi_x(A)=\phi_x(Ap)$, hence $p\geq$ the support projection of $\phi_x$, ie there is a support projection less than $p$!